# Create an optimization model such that selecting start date and end date produces some outcome

Tags: r, dataframe

```
     21-Oct 28-Oct  4-Nov 11-Nov
22-Apr   90     95      95    95    
29-Apr   95     100     100   100   
6-May    95     100     100   100   
13-May   90     100     100   95    
20-May   90     95      95    90    
27-May   80     85      85    90    
3-Jun    75     80      80    85
```

`
The data above shows the start dates (rows) and end dates (columns) and values represent outcomes in percentage terms given start and end dates. I want to create an optimization model such that selecting start date and end date produces an outcome using R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to this question is how to subset the data frame based on row and column names. Here I designed a function to achieve this. To use this function, you can set `start` to the start date, `end` to the end date, and `dt` to your data frame.

```
outcome <- function(start, end, dt){
  out <- dt[rownames(dt) %in% start, colnames(dt) %in% end]
  return(out)
}

# Example:
outcome(start = "29-Apr", end = "28-Oct", dt = dat)
# [1] 100
```

Or as mentioned in the comment, you can do the following directly.

```
outcome <- function(start, end, dt){
  out <- dt[start, end]
  return(out)
}
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "'22-Apr'   90     95      95    95    
'29-Apr'   95     100     100   100   
'6-May'    95     100     100   100   
'13-May'   90     100     100   95    
'20-May'   90     95      95    90    
'27-May'   80     85      85    90    
'3-Jun'    75     80      80    85", header = FALSE, row.names = 1)

names(dat) <- c("21-Oct", "28-Oct", "4-Nov", "11-Nov")
```

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. I have updated my answer based on your comment.